# Change J2ME application vendor

Tags: java-me

I have to update my J2ME application but I can't use old vendor name because of legal issues. A lot of phones compares application name and vendor while install application. If application vendors not identical then user gets two different applications with the same name. Is there a way to migrate from the old to the new application without getting two different applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Java-ME security will not allow you that. The sandbox makes sure that no app can manipulate another app from a different vendor.

So you are in an unfortunate situation and you have not much options for your existing users. If you have stored data into the RMS, and the RMS is not made public, the user also looses the data.
All that might be possible is to update the old app into a dummy app that tells the user to download the new app (and make your RMS public, so the new app can read it.).